# Managed Keyed State not restoring with Check pointing Enabled

Tags: apache-flink

EDIT2: skip to the end, state is restored but it's not queryable new tl;dr **"How do I make State that was queryable, still queryable after a restore from checkpoint?"**

I have a keyed stream with check pointing enabled similar to this (I've tried this with in memory as well as HDFS with the same results)

```
env.enableCheckpointing(60000)
env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("file:///flink-test"))
val stream = env.addSource(consumer)
  .flatMap(new ValidationMap()).name("ValidationMap")
  .keyBy(x => new Tuple3[String, String, String](x.account(), x.organization(), x.`type`()))
  .flatMap(new Foo()).name(jobname)
```

Within this stream, I have a Managed Keyed State ValueState that I set as queryable.

```
  val newValueStateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor[java.util.ArrayList[java.util.ArrayList[Long]]]("foo", classOf[java.util.ArrayList[java.util.ArrayList[Long]]])
  newValueStateDescriptor.setQueryable("foo")

  valueState = getRuntimeContext.getState[java.util.ArrayList[java.util.ArrayList[Long]]](newValueStateDescriptor)
  valueState.update(new java.util.ArrayList[java.util.ArrayList[Long]]())
```

This list is periodically appended to or removed from and the valueState is updated.  When I make a request of the Queryable State I currently see correct values.

In my JobManager log I see check pointing every minute, and when I check the file system, I see files being created that are non-empty.

My setup has 3 JobManagers (2 in standby), 3 TaskManagers (all 3 in use).

I put a single data point into the system and read it out of QueryableState, everything looks good.  Then I pick a single TaskManager (not even the one that processed the data, any of the 3) and I kill it, then restart it to simulate a crash.

I watch the job get retried 2 or 3 times until the TaskManager comes back online, and finally I see the same JobID running again in Flink, life seems good.

But, I then hit the Queryable State again, and I get an UnknownKvStateLocation exception.

I'm really not quite sure what I've done wrong here, things appear to be check pointing, but I never manage to get my ValueState back ?  Maybe it's back but not Queryable?

EDIT:
Log snippet from JobManager implies things are restored

```
{"level":"INFO","time":"2017-06-01 15:30:02,332","class":"org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph","ndc":"", "message":"Job Foo (dc7850a6866f181c2f07968d35fe3d46) switched from state RESTARTING to CREATED."}
{"level":"INFO","time":"2017-06-01 15:30:02,332","class":"org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.ZooKeeperCompletedCheckpointStore","ndc":"", "message":"Recovering checkpoints from ZooKeeper."}
{"level":"INFO","time":"2017-06-01 15:30:02,333","class":"org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.ZooKeeperCompletedCheckpointStore","ndc":"", "message":"Found 1 checkpoints in ZooKeeper."}
{"level":"INFO","time":"2017-06-01 15:30:02,333","class":"org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.ZooKeeperCompletedCheckpointStore","ndc":"", "message":"Trying to retrieve checkpoint 5."}
{"level":"INFO","time":"2017-06-01 15:30:02,340","class":"org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator","ndc":"", "message":"Restoring from latest valid checkpoint: Checkpoint 5 @ 1496330912627 for dc7850a6866f181c2f07968d35fe3d46."}
{"level":"INFO","time":"2017-06-01 15:30:02,340","class":"org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph","ndc":"", "message":"Job Foo (dc7850a6866f181c2f07968d35fe3d46) switched from state CREATED to RUNNING."}
```

It *really* looks like it's restored, and when I inspect the file created in /flink-test I see some binary data but it contains the identifying names for my Queryable State ValueState.  Any ideas on what to look for would be welcome.

EDIT2: State >is< restored, it's just not queryable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that a given piece of registered state has been made queryable is not (currently) part of what Flink records in checkpoints or savepoints. So after recovery, the state isn't queryable until a new StateDescriptor is provided.

For more, see [this discussion](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201706.mbox/%3CetPan.59313353.301e763.1625d@apache.org%3E) on the flink-users mailing list.